# Github Pages Custom Domain Not Showing In Settings

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm trying to add a custom domain to my github pages repository in settings but I must be dumb or something as I don't see an option to add a custom domain :/
[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you click on the git hub repository you want to add a custom domain to, then settings look for Custom domain and then put the domain in there

Comment: The screenshot above is in the settings section you're mentioning and the "Custom Domain" option is missing.

Comment: Go to Settings, and then on the menu down the left hand side click on Pages, it's in there.